# Differences in impact of neo liberalism on different social segments (urban vs. rural)

Tags: liberalism, neoliberalism

How does neo liberalism as a political project impacts lives of both urban and rural population, differently?

For example, in India, urban population hardly see their elected government playing any role in their life. Instead there are corporations, which play larger role in their life. They provide employment and various other services like education, health care. Government is nearly non existent among them. But in the case of rural population, Government still plays few roles like procuring agricultural products at minimum support price, providing health care,etc..

Is neo liberalism designed to operate differently among both rural and urban population in third world countries?

Comment: Please clarify if you mean neoliberalism in the sense of the *Washington Consensus* or in the sense of the *Social Market Economy.* Both were labeled neoliberal, half a century apart. Also, if you ask about worldwide effects, are you aware of the differences of the urban-rural divide e.g. in Scandinavia and in India?

Comment: By Neo liberalism, I mean Washington consensus which is followed by privatization and globalization. I understand the fundamental difference between first world countries and third world countries. Though I have specified "worldwide" in my question, I really meant neoliberalism's impact on urban, rural population in third world countries. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Some one, please add "Neo liberalism" tag to this question. I am unable to add.

Comment: wouldn't it make sense that the government does **not** provide much assistance to populations that can pay for themselves?  Education and health are candidates to be kept within government scope as the market does not align very well with providing it.  But things like food and housing might be better *purchased*, from the market, rather than *handed out* by the govt, *if people can afford them*.  So, you recenter govt help on the poor.  No the rich, not the urban middle class.

Comment: South Asian countries including India are extremely poor. Rich is very small percentage of the society. Unless government spend enough for social welfare, their population would find difficulty to meet their ends. Neo liberalism demand states to withdraw from interfering in market dynamics and leave everything to Market, which is suicidal for a society like India. Indian state has withdrawn from almost all spheres of urban lives. However, they fear somekind of popular movement to emerge in rural area if similar kind of withdrawal happen there.

Comment: @workingclass_science there's a bit of a problem in your statement.  if *everyone* gets $500 worth of services "cuz poor" and *everyone* is poor, then *everyone* is paying $500 worth of taxes + govt ineffficiency factor to get those $500 worth of services.  best to have everyone pay less in tax, but retarget the aid to those most in need, not Mr and Mrs Averagely-Poor Person.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica "best to have everyone pay less in tax" I thought the idea of taxes is also redistribution, so tax the rich and give to the poor for example. Can still be done even within neo liberalism.

Comment: @Trilarion I didnt say it couldnt.  I said a model - running on whatever -ism you want - where everyone gets subsidies wont work.  And if you have lots and lots of poor people there is no way "tax the few rich" will get you large scale subsidies.  That's just common sense math.

Comment: @Trilarion I didnt say it couldnt.  I said a model - running on whatever -ism you want - where everyone gets subsidies wont work.  And if you have lots and lots of poor people there is no way "tax the few rich" will get you large scale subsidies.  That's just common sense math.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Let me quote from Oxfam report "Many ordinary Indians are not able to access the health care they need. 63 million of them are pushed into poverty because of healthcare costs every year - almost two people every second." At the same time "The top 10% of the Indian population holds 77% of the total national wealth. 73% of the wealth generated in 2017 went to the richest 1%, while 67 million Indians who comprise the poorest half of the population saw only a 1% increase in their wealth." The income is getting distributed, anyway, towards richest.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica In addition, Neo liberalism helps corporates to drain the state, all the resources. The state become resourceless and corporates become resourceful. This makes the inequality problem more severe. Taxing is the only meaningful tool to reverse this trend.

Comment: @workingclass_science well, I see you have all the answers figured out already.  one thing I am curious about is why anyone would think India, of all places, is being run by neoliberals, but I have no doubt you'll have an answer for that too.  I would say that wrt to your question, india seems to have a considerable urban-rural wealth gap, which may explain different services.  but I will doubtless be informed that because all of India is poor undoubtedly all of India deserves equal subsidies.  I upvoted the Q myself, but I'll bow out now.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I doubt if the question came out properly as myself was not clear about how to frame this question. The intention behind this question is to figure out, if neo liberalism is being internalized by urban population, unlike rural population. I could see huge protest from rural population in India when state attempt to withdraw from its basic services while Urban population seems to adjusting with similar kind of state withdrawal.